# Handle DialogFragment onClick events in Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, asynchronous

I have an android app that has a DialogFragment that calls an async process (it's called "api.Async" in the code sample below). When finished, I want to show another activity with the result. I keep receiving "**Fragment [Name] not attached to activity.**" How can I fix this? And once it's done, how can I send information to the new activity?

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_lookup, null);

    builder.setView(view)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.lookup, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    EditText text = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.username);

                    api.Async("GetByID/", text.getText().toString(), new badgerAPI.IApiResultRunnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run(CMAPIResult apiResult) {
                            if (!apiResult.lmSuccess) {
                                showError(view.getContext(), "User not found", apiResult.lmErrorMessage).show();
                            } else {
                                String badgeuri = apiResult.lmResultDict.optString("badgeuri");

//APPLICATION ERRORS IN FOLLOWING FUNCTION
                                showBadge(view.getContext(), badgeuri);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                }
            });
    ;

    return builder.create();
}
```

The "showBadge" function is very simple:

```
private void showBadge(final Context act, String uri){
    Intent intent = new Intent(act, DisplayBadge.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

I've tried several different ways:

getActivity()

view.GetContext();

[Class].this (won't even compile)

What are the ways I can get around a fragment (that closes by the time the activity is done) and showing a view from a function in the results?

Thanks!

Comment: You can only start activities from the main ("ui") thread. What does the `api.Async` implementation look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your DialogFragent has been destroyed by the time the async process has completed. To make it work correctly, start the async process from the Activity instead of the DialogFragment.

So, in the DialogFragment just call back into a public method in the Activity that will do the heavy lifting (`doPositiveClick()` in this example):

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_lookup, null);

    builder.setView(view)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.lookup, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    EditText text = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.username);

                    //call into the Activity and pass in the name                        
                    ((MainActivity)getActivity()).doPositiveClick(text.getText().toString());

                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                }
            });

    return builder.create();
}
```

Then, in your Activity that called the DialogFragment, initiate the async process, and start the DisplayBadge Activity when it's completed.

Note I've changed the method definitions and some of the code, as there is no need to pass around a Context anymore:

```
public void doPositiveClick(String name) {
   api.Async("GetByID/", name, new badgerAPI.IApiResultRunnable() {
     @Override
     public void run(CMAPIResult apiResult) {
       if (!apiResult.lmSuccess) {
         showError(this, "User not found", apiResult.lmErrorMessage).show();
       } else {
         String badgeuri = apiResult.lmResultDict.optString("badgeuri");

         showBadge(badgeuri);
       }
     }
   });

}

private void showBadge(String uri){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayBadge.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: That works, thanks! I figured it had to be something like that, but wasn't sure about the lifespans and how to check that - tried every variant but this :)

Answer (score 0):

A far cleaner solution is to add an interface in the dialog as one would in a recycler adapter.

```
class YourDialog(val listener: OnReprintClickListener): DialogFragment() {

    interface OnReprintClickListener {
        fun onPostiveClick()
        fun onNegClick()
    }

}
```

Then in your activity you would implement the class

```
class YourActivity : ReprintDialog.OnReprintClickListener {

    override fun onPositiveClick() {
        enter code here
    }
    override fun onNegClick() {
        enter code here
    }
}
```

Then do something